# Present perfect and since f

Tags: present-perfect

1 Aunt Gloria has not visited us since she has been working abroad

2 Aunt Gloria has not visited us since she worked/ was workig abroad

Is there any difcerence between these two sentences?

Comment: I would say "Aunt Gloria has not visited us since she began working abroad." or "Aunt Gloria has not visited us since she started working abroad."

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us what specifically you are confused about or what you already know.

Comment: I'd like to paraphrasie this 1 sentence with last do you know how

Comment: Note, there's potential in both cases to take "since" to mean "because."

Comment: Meanwhile: This question is currently too simple for a good answer. Please use the "Edit" button, not the comment area, to tell what meaning or shades of meaning you would like to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence implies that she is still working abroad whereas the second implies that she is no longer working abroad.